# How to calculate adjusted and normalized fitness when a higher raw fitness is better

Tags: genetic-algorithms, genetic-programming, fitness-functions

I am reading *Genetic Programming: On the Programming of Computers by Means of Natural Selection* by John R. Koza.

- For calculating the "standardized fitness" of an individual, where a *lower* raw fitness score is better:

  $s_i = r_i$

  where $s_i$ is the standardized fitness, and $r_i$ is the raw fitness of the individual. Lower standardized fitness scores correspond to fitter individuals.

  In problems where an individual with a *higher* raw fitness score is better, Koza suggests this:

  $s_i = r_{max} - r_{i}$
- The adjusted fitness of each individual is $0 <= a <= 1$, and it is calculated like this:

  $a_i = \frac{1}{1 + s_i}$

  Higher adjusted fitness scores correspond to fitter individuals.
- The normalized fitness is calculated like this:

  $n_i = \frac{a_i}{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{M}{a_k}}$

  where $M$ is the number of individuals in the population.

  The sum of the normalized fitness of all individuals equals to $1$.

My issue is this: in problems where individuals with a higher raw fitness score are fitter than those with lower raw fitness scores, and $r_{max}$ is not known, how do I calculate the adjusted fitness and normalized fitness?

This is my approach:

- Ignore the standardized fitness, and calculate the adjusted fitness scores directly using raw fitness scores.
- $a_i = 1 - \frac{1}{1 + r_i}$
- $n_i = \frac{a_i}{\sum\limits_{k=1}^{M}{a_k}}$ (same as the textbook).

This seems to works well. However, to my surprise, the textbook is suggesting a different method (section 6.3.2):

> If no upper bound $r_{max}$ is known and a bigger value of raw fitness is better, the adjusted fitness and the normalized fitness (both described below) can be computed directly from the raw fitness. If a smaller value of raw fitness is better and no lower bound is known, the sign can be reversed and the adjusted fitness and the normalized fitness can be computed directly from the raw fitness.

This suggestion is most puzzling:

- When a bigger value of raw fitness is better, the book is suggesting to use $a_i = \frac{1}{1 + r_i}$, but higher $r$ values will produce lower $a$ values, which is wrong because higher $a$ is supposed to correspond to fitter individuals!
- When a smaller value of raw fitness is better, the book suggesting to "reverse the sign". This would make all $a$ values negative. It would also make $n$ wrong because the weakest individuals will end up having the highest normalized fitness values!

So, please help me understand the quote above. How do I calculate the adjusted fitness and normalized fitness when higher raw fitness scores correspond to fitter individuals?